# How to get Apache Camel, RabbitMQ and transactions working?

Tags: spring, transactions, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I've looked everywhere and I cannot find out how to get these two to work using transactions. I can find examples with Spring, Camel, ActiveMQ and transactions but never with RabbitMQ.

Comment: Please share what have you done so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the current [RabbitMQ Camel Component](https://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html) that feature is not implemented. If you really want to use transactions with RabbitMQ and Camel, you will need to change the code to allow the component to do this.

The exact you would need to modify would be [this one](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=camel.git;a=blob;f=components/camel-rabbitmq/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/rabbitmq/RabbitMQProducer.java;h=7763423f7b1e9685b26bf9d861a68ff01aa61ebe;hb=HEAD) around the `channel.basicPublish()` call.

Comment: If I have read this correctly transactions have not been built into apache camel with rabbitmq?